# Migrate a webpart from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part, migration

How to migrate a webpart connected with 8 lists from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013. What should I do before migration and what prepere before migration. How to transfer from .net 3,5 to .net 4,5. Should I transfer from 3,5 to 4,5 .net ?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 uses App Model for development. So you need to take a decision what approach you should follow.

Also SP 2013 encourages using CSOM as opposed to Farm Solutions.

If you have only limited time, then I think you can directly deploy 2010 solution and test what functionality is breaking, then try to fix only that.

Comment: Yes I know about App Model Client Side, but I don't wont to write again webpart, because my webpart has got about 2000 lines of code. But How can I deploy as 2010 instantion ?

Comment: Its backward compatible. I recently did the same with one of my solution. And it worked.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to change something in code in WebPart at Sharepoint 2013 it still work ? OrI must migrate all Sharepoint Development to Sharepoint 2013?